# Вызов события onmouseover

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

У меня есть событие, при котором, когда наводишь курсор на изображение, оно меняется поочередно на другие (указан путь к папке, где эти изображения). Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать так, чтобы при наведении на ссылку у меня менялось изображение, т.е. не при наведении на изображение, а на ссылку происходило то же самое.

Html

```
<a href="#">
<img class="img" data-original="http://site.com/img/1.jpg" onmouseover="rotationStart(this, 'http://site.com/img/', 10)" onmouseout="rotationStop(this)">
<span class="duration">QWERTY</span>
</a>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() { rotationEngineStartup(0.2, 0.5)}, 1500);
</script>
```

Comment: @Mac2k8, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Comment: Вопрос решен, нашел похожий скрипт

Comment: @Mac2k8, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Код может очень серьезно меняться в зависимости от того, как Вы достаете изображения и будете передавать на исполнение. В вопросе о этом нет ни слова или хотя бы кода, который работает с изображениями, то вот Вам вольная и простая интерпретация желания:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="images/icons/55/1.png" class="img_to_change">
<a href="#" class="change_image">Change image</a>
```

**Javascript & Jquery library:**

```
var timeoutId;
var img = 2;

$(".change_image")

.mouseenter(function(){
  timeoutId = setInterval(function(){
     $(".img_to_change").attr("src","../images/icons/55/"+(img++)+".png");
  },1000);
})

.mouseleave(function(){
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```